# Issue with Azure AD B2C with an Identity Provider and PKCE

Tags: identityserver4, azure-ad-b2c, pkce

I have set up a B2C identity provider pointing to the online test version of IdentityServer4:

https://demo.identityserver.io

My app registration is for a SPA application.

My user policy is a standard SUSI one.

Using the "Run now" option, the following parameters are sent:

```
p: B2C_1_SUSI_B2C
client_id: 5e58...620a
nonce: defaultNonce
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
scope: openid
response_type: code
prompt: login
code_challenge_method: S256
code_challenge: D9pGhYDch4f8F3V0MsDvaEQWH3-ssqucs3ixxTAgX6k
```

This contains the PKCE parameters as expected.

I get the B2C login screen and click the IdentityServer4 button.

The following parameters are sent to IdentityServer4:

```
client_id: interactive.public
redirect_uri: https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp
response_type: code
scope: openid
response_mode: form_post
nonce: HZ0avacgvKw5Jyp6W4k1Tw==
ui_locales: en-US
state: StateProperties=eyJTSUQiOiJ4....
```

Notice that there are no longer any PKCE parameters.

IdentityServer4 responds:

```
Error
Sorry, there was an error : invalid_request
code challenge required
```

How do you get the PKCE parameters to be forwarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible right now. There is also almost no value to use PKCE here as it is a confidential client flow.

Comment: Yep, although there's no problem with "beefing up" server-side confidential client requests with PKCE it doesn't really achieve anything. That doesn't mean your customers won't insist on it though (ask me how I know ;) ).

Comment: Understood, but it means for IdentityServer you have to explicitly turn PKCE off for this app.

Comment: Doesn't PKCE still help a confidential client defend against code injection? The OAuth 2.1 draft recommends PKCE for confidential clients: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-01#section-9.8

Comment: I did a focused write-up on my blog. Let me know what you think  https://www.scottbrady91.com/oauth/client-authentication-vs-pkce

Comment: @ScottBrady I was not aware of that, I will give it a read :)